# Linking QSsh Botan-2 std::thread

Tags: multithreading, botan

I compiled successfully BOTAN-2 (botan.exe BOTAN-test.exe runnable).

When I build QSsh's Project under Qt Creator I've got a linking error on std::thead (Compiler MinGW32)

```
rsa.cpp:-1: erreur : undefined reference to std::thread::_State::~_State()
rsa.cpp:-1: erreur : undefined reference to std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State,  std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)())
```

A added unsuccessfully in the file qssh/src/libs/ssh.pro :

```
LIBS += -lbotan-2
LIBS += -lpthread
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -std=c++11 -pthread
QMAKE_CFLAGS += -std=c++11 -pthread
```

Note : I made a simple program ("hello world" style) using pthread with success.

```
g++ main.cpp -o build32/prog.exe -std=c++11 -pthread    (MSYS2/MinGW32)
```

What's wrong with QSsh ?

Thanks